# Dual Of Integer Network Formulation

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, network-flow

I have the following IP and I wonder how to write the dual of it
as a network flow problem:

\begin{align}
\max & \sum_{i \in N} w_ix_i \\[4pt]
\text{s.t. } & x_i \leq x_j, \forall (i,j) \in A \\[10pt]
& 0 \leq x_i \leq 1, \forall i \in N
\end{align}

I was thinking that the dual could be:

\begin{align}
\min & \sum_{i \in N} z_{i} \\[4pt]
\text{s.t. } & \sum_{(i,j)} y_{ij} - \sum_{(j,i)} y_{ji} \geq 0, \forall i \in N \\[10pt]
&z_{i} \geq w_{i} , \forall i \in N\\
& y_{ij} \geq0 , \forall (i,j) \in A
\end{align}

but I am not sure. what changes do I need to do to make the dual formulation correct?

Answer (score 1):

There are three errors: (1) Because $y_{ij}$ is associated to the constraint where the right hand side is 0 ($x_i - x_i \leq 0$), it should not appear in the objective. (2) The coefficients $w_i$ seem to be missing in the dual. (3) You currently do not have a dual variable associated to the constraint $x_i \leq 1$.

This seems to be the correct dual to me:
\begin{align}
\min & \sum_{i \in N} z_{i} \\[4pt]
\text{s.t. } & z_i + \sum_{j : (i,j) \in A} y_{ij} - \sum_{j : (j,i)\in A} y_{ji} \geq 0, \forall i \in N \\[10pt]
& y_{ij} \geq0 , \forall (i,j) \in A \\
& z_i \geq 0, \forall i \in N
\end{align}

Comment: I added k_{i} as another variable and changed the formulation .. does it look as a valid network flow problem ? (I think it might be a shortest path problem but not sure).

Comment: @Bassem $k_i$ should appear in a constraint (the problem currently has a trivial optimal solution), and I suggest to use $z_i$ instead of $k_i$ to stick to the convention of using the last letters of the alphabet for variables. Also what is $i \in A$? If you do it correctly, it should not be a shortest path problem.

Comment: $ i \in N $ is the number of variables .. I changed the formulation .. does it seem right?

Comment: Not quite. Your dual has $2n$ constraints while the primal only has $n$ variables. Those 2 should be equal. You still have $i \in A$ in the objective.

Comment: I changed A to N .. however, I am not sure how to correct the unequal variables and constriants. where do you think the problem is?

Comment: I have updated my answer. For an interpretation, think of $y_{ij}$ as numbers to put on the arcs, and $z_i$ to be associated with the vertices. I expect the result to be similar to a max-flow min-cut result in the context of your primal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75360/discussion-between-bassem-and-linalg).